# Verifying the accuracy of rejection sampling using hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, rejection-sampling

Say we wish to generate i.i.d samples from a distribution with density $f(x)$, and we do so using rejection sampling. How can "verify" that the generated distribution is "correct"? I.e can we use something like KS to test for the closeness of our generated distribution to our desired one, using only the fact that we know what density it is supposed to have?

The reason I ask this is becuse I was reading a document regarding rejection sampling, and it said "after a sample has been generated (using rejection sampling), we can apply usual tests on the generated sample". (The document was vague on what exactly was to be tested)

Now I simply assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that the paper was talking about some kind of distributional comparison, but maybe they were talking about other tests. Am I missing some context of "standard procedure" regarding rejection sampling tests?

---

TL;DR: What can we test about a sample generated with rejection sampling, since we only know the desired density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rejection sampling, namely simulating $x_i$'s from a density $g$ until a uniform $u_i$ is less than $f(x_i)/Mg(x_i)$ is an exact way of simulating from $f$ when $f(x)\le Mg(x)$ everywhere. Because it is equivalent to simulating a uniform $(V,X)$ on the subgraph of $f$:
$$\left\{(v,x);\ 0\le v\le f(x)\right\}$$([fundamental theorem of simulation](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR)). 
There is thus nothing to check at this level.

If one is uncertain about the bound $M$ used in the algorithm, i.e., if it may be too small, then a KS test can indeed be used to check that the sample is from the assumed distribution, but this is on principle and rather formal since, if rejection sampling is required for simulating from $f$, the associated cdf is most likely intractable and hence the KS test cannot be used in practice. A more practical approach is thus to check that $M$ is large enough: I vaguely remember [a paper by Bruno Goffinet in Biometrika (1996)](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/83/4/791/253390?redirectedFrom=PDF) learning sequentially about the constant $M$.